# jQuery - Split single table row into rows of three columns

Tags: jquery, html

I have a database that outputs a table in a single row, I need to use jQuery to split the single row into multiple rows of three columns, it would also be good if I could change a value to make it multiple rows of 4 or 5 in the future.

HTML Output example

```
<table class="staff">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Result required

[image]

**Note**, I can not write jQuery, so I manipulate exisiting scripts, I have found the script below, it creates multiples of 2 columns per row however when I try and mess with the values I can't get it to display 3 columns per row.

jQuery

```
$("table.staff td").each(function(index) {
  var odd = isOdd((index + 1));
  if (odd) {
    $("table.staff tbody").append($("<tr>"));
  }
  $("table.staff tr").last().append($(this));
});
$("table.staff tr").first().remove();

function isOdd(num) {
  return num % 2;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/ehyoLr4u/)

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the `td` and then use the [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) get the desired number of items per row, and then append them to the `tbody`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let tds = $('td');
  let len = tds.length;
  let itemsPerRow = 3;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i = i + itemsPerRow) {
    $('tbody').append($('<tr></tr>')).append(tds.splice(0, itemsPerRow));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="staff" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, just noticed when I used your solution in my project the source code of the table doesn't look correct, there are <tr></tr> between the td's not on either side, could you possibly have a look.

Comment: Don't worry, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the existing solution in my project. The source code of the table doesn't look correct. There are `<tr></tr>` tags between the `TD` tags, not on either side. Could someone possibly have a look?