# Rearrange existing table using jquery or pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to rearrange an existing dynamic table with jquery or pure javascript.
I already found **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59296011)** post on stackoverflow that is exactly what I am looking for but
the given solution doesn't work for me.

I have some Problems with this Script.

1.) There is an unwanted `<tr></tr>` element at the top and there will be one more with every code execution.

2.) I can not use this code on just one table. If I use `$('#example tbody')` and add an id to the table it disappears.

3.) It's not working on the Internet Explorer.

Maybe someone can help

Comment: You're using "pure" JavaScript whether or not you use jQuery (unless you use TypeScript or something). The contrast you're looking for is "using jQuery" vs. "using the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) directly." Knowing that makes it easier to search for the information you need.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ask just one question per post going forward. You have three distinct issues listed up there.

Answer (score 0):

The post you mentioned shows how it's getting done, especially the splitting and adding part. The rest depends on your requirements, so you have to tweak the code to get the expected behavior.

1. To get rid of the tr-tag you could simply remove the children of tbody, so you have a clean element.
2. If you want to limit it for a specific table you could add an id to that table and change the selectors accordingly.
3. Couldn't reproduce. Works also in IE.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rearrange").click(function(){
    
    let tds = $('#rearrangeTable td');
    let len = tds.length;
    let randomItemsPerRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 2;
    let itemsPerRow = randomItemsPerRow;
    $("#rearrangeTable tbody").children().remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i = i + itemsPerRow) {
      $('#rearrangeTable tbody').append($('<tr></tr>')).append(tds.splice(0, itemsPerRow));
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="rearrange">
 Rearrange
</button>
<table id="rearrangeTable" class="staff" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thx for your help but now the sorting is different & it's still not working in ie but the <tr></tr> problem is solved. I added my current script.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer for my question, that also works in Internet Explorer now.

Thx ;-)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" ></script>

<script>

     function letsgo() {

          var tds = $('#example td');
          var len = tds.length;
          var itemsPerRow = 3;

          $("#example tbody").children().remove();

          for (var i = 0; i < len; i = i + itemsPerRow) {
               $('#example tbody').append($('<tr>'));
               $('#example tbody tr:last').append(tds.splice(0, itemsPerRow));
               $('#example tbody').append($('</tr>'));
          };
     }

</script>

<button onclick="letsgo();">Rearrange</button>

<table id="example" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```